# CSS text overflow fade

Tags: css

How can I emulate `-webkit-mask-image` CSS property on Firefox and other browsers?

I need to create text fade effect on text overflow.
For Chrome I've done something like this:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 98%);
```

How can I do this effect for other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Except webkit browser no browser is supported by mask image. You need to go for any alternative.

Comment: I have to draw this mask.svg myself or its rendered by browser?

Comment: @user1858864: Check it in mozilla browser, I dont have browser to check.